# extension of a homeomorphism to a compact pseudo metric space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism such that $f(a)= a$ and $X\cap \mathbb{N}=\emptyset$.

In my research I need to construct a compact pseudo metric $(X\cup\mathbb{N}, \rho)$ and  homeomorphism $g$ on $X\cup\mathbb{N}$ such that $g|X=f$ and $g(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For this purpose in the following, I give a solution for it:

Let $Y=X\cup\mathbb{N}$ and $\rho:Y\times Y\to[0, \infty)$ define by  $\rho(n, m)=0$ and $\rho(x, n)= d(x, a)$ and $\rho(m, y)=d(a, y)$ if $x,y\in X$ and $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Also $g:Y\to Y$ be defined by $g(y)= f(y)$ if $y\in X$ and $g(n)=n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Please help me to know that my proof is true?

Comment: Your proof is correct. However, if you would like that $\rho$ be a metric. You could define $\rho$ as $$\rho(x,y) = 
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
1,\ \mbox{if} \ x \in X \ \mbox{and} \ y \in \mathbb{N},\\
|x-y|,\ \mbox{if} \ x,y \in \mathbb{N},\\
d(x,y),\ \mbox{if} \ x,y \in X,
\end{array}\right.$$
your demonstration still works using this definition of $\rho$. Moreover your assumption that $f(a) = a$ is not necessary.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto,Thanks. What say about compactness of $Y$ in my proof. Is it true that $(Y, \rho)$ is a compact pseudo metric spaces and $g:Y\to Y$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: sorry for my comment, I made a mistake, did not realize that you wanted $Y$ to be compact (my metric does not work for your purposes). I'll think again in your question